# How do I make Battleship ships longer than one space?

Tags: python

I am making a Battleship game with Python.

I can't figure out how to make the ships longer than one space.

Here is my code:

```
    x = 0
    def game():
    while x == 0:
    from random import randint
    board = []
    row_num = 1
    hit = 0
    for i in range(1,11):
        board.append(10*["O"])
        row_num += 1

    def print_board(board):
        for row in board:
            print(" ".join(row))

    print("Let's Play Battleship!") 
    print("Turn 1")
    print_board(board)

    def random_row(board):
        return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

    def random_col(board):
        return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

    ship1_row = random_row(board)
    ship1_col = random_col(board)

    ship2_row = random_row(board)
    ship2_col = random_col(board)

    ship3_row = random_row(board)
    ship3_col = random_col(board)

    def check_ship2():
        if ship2_row == ship1_row and ship2_col == ship1_col:
            ship2_row = random_row(board)
            ship2_col = random_col(board)
            return ship2_row
            return ship2_col
            check_ship2()

    def check_ship3():
        if ship3_row == ship1_row and ship3_col == ship1_col:
            ship3_row = random_row(board)
            ship3_col = random_col(board)
            return ship3_row
            return ship3_col
            check_ship3()
        elif ship3_row == ship2_row and ship3_col == ship2_col:
            ship3_row = random_row(board)
            ship3_col = random_col(board)
            return ship3_row
            return ship3_col
            check_ship3()   

    def restart():
        again = input("Do You want to play again?(Y/N)")
        if again == "Y" or again == "y":
            print("\n" * 80)
            game()
        elif again == "N" or again == "n":
            print("Thanks for playing!")
            exit()
        else:
            print("Sorry that wasn't Y or N, try again")
            restart()   

    for turn in range(1,16):
        guess_row = int(input("Guess Row with a number 0-9:"))
        guess_col = int(input("Guess Col with a number 0-9:"))
        print("\n" * 80)
        if (guess_row == ship1_row and guess_col == ship1_col) or (guess_row == ship2_row and guess_col == ship2_col) or (guess_row == ship3_row and guess_col == ship3_col):
            board[guess_row][guess_col] = "S"
            print("Congratulations! You sank my battleship!")
            hit += 1            
        else:
            if (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 9) or (guess_col < 0 or guess_col > 9):
                print("Oops, that's not even in the ocean!")
            elif (board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X"):
                print("You guessed that one already!")
            else:
                print("You missed my battleship!")
                board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"
            if turn == 15:
                print("Game Over")
                board[ship1_row][ship1_col] = "S"
                board[ship2_row][ship2_col] = "S"
                board[ship3_row][ship3_col] = "S"
                print_board(board)
                print("The first ship was at row number " + str(ship1_row) + " and column number " + str(ship1_col))
                print("The second ship was at row number " + str(ship2_row) + " and column number " + str(ship2_col))
                print("The third ship was at row number " + str(ship3_row) + " and column number " + str(ship3_col))
                print(restart())
        if hit == 3:
            print("You sank all of my battleships!")
            print("You Win!")
            print_board(board)
            restart()       
        print ("Turn " + str(turn + 1))
        print_board(board)
    game()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hei watch out! In your code you are doing something really wrong:

if you return a value that's it...so it makes no sense to continue with additional lines. Please check how you can pass your boat to the program.

```
return ship3_row
return ship3_col
check_ship3()
```

For sure a good option to choose where to put the boat is to use a list, where you store all the points of a ship.

If the person is finding all the points of a ship...then the ship is destroyed.
Hope this help a bit...have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks for the fix and the idea, but I am still kinda new to coding, so I'm not exactly sure how I would put the ships in a list. Could you show me an example or like explain how I would do it?

Comment: Hi...If you need a code that is working then just use the one here http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578836-the-game-of-battleships-in-python/ This is working as a lot of other examples you can easily found.

Comment: If I were you a better idea would be to start from the scratch and maybe learn also the TK module for the use of canvas and graphical parts...it is a bit tough, but it gave you a nice idea of coding :-)

Comment: Another comment is that you can improve really fast in python...for instance while True: will have the same effect of your x == 0 --> this you should avoid...then you can learn about "break" --> to go out of a loop...in case all the ships are destroyed. Hope the example is enough :-) and I hope you can vote my reply as fine!! Have a nice day.

Comment: The link sent is in python2.x hope this is not a problem...just exchange the print "something" with print("something) :-) the code is really basic one, but it's worth to play against pc :-)

Comment: Thank you very much, my friend actually just gave me the very same idea of starting from scratch. I think it is a great idea as I will be able to write the code with the changes in mind this time instead of needing to go back through and change everything to fit with the new stuff. Once again thanks, this helped a lot.

Comment: Always welcome and have a great day!